# Hide the title of an NSMenuItem, just show its image?

Tags: cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsmenu

I have an `NSMenu` (belonging to an `NSPopUpButton`) where the `NSMenuItem` all have images set and I'd like them to display only the images, not the titles.  I can't unset the titles, though, since they provide keyboard accessibility (and, I think, other accessibility).  Is there some way to hide the title, like the image position `NSImageOnly` for `NSButton`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary workaround that doesn't really make me happy:

Instead of setting the title of the `NSMenuItem`, set the attributed title to the attributed string of the intended title with the system font in an invisibly-small size, such as 0.01.

Comment: It hurts to +1 this, but this seems to be the most reliable solution for Cocoa AppKit.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the first item in the menu, it works fine when done this way:

1. Instantiate the `NSPopUpButton` in Interface Builder
2. Set to type Pull down, style Square, and set an image.
3. Make the position image only (the second option in the palette)

These settings all pertain to the button part of the control, but it will create a menu with the first item being an image-only menu item. Actually, the title is not set (as evidenced by the placeholder being shown in the title field). This should mean that yo can set the title to `nil` in case you do it programmatically.

Comment: I think that when it's set to pull-down instead of pop-up, the first menu item is always shown in the button and not in the menu (whereas in pop-up, the selected menu item is shown in the button and all menu items, including the first one, are shown in the menu).  That is, when I tried this, my first menu item was no longer shown in the menu and all my subsequent menu items still showed both their images and their titles.